# using php to serve CSS files

Tags: php, css, dynamic-css

Is this a good idea to serve a css file by php ?

Actually I have a large CSS file which include all media query so I thought to serve only selected section based on the argument passed to the php page 
Eg In my original php page I will do like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.php?<?= "theam=".$theam ."&screen=".$screen ?>"/>
```

and in the css.php file I will check the condition to give response with only required css is this the correct Way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's ok as long as you add headers:

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
```

And make sure you check the `$_GET` for correct values

Another suggestion is changing the url to some nicer ones with rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^css-(.*)-(.*)\.css$  /css.php?theam=$1&screen=$2
```

Comment: yes i know that but is it a correct way of doing it don't you think it will increase the response time for the css resource

Comment: Maybe by few microseconds until the script is executed, but that is not a problem. There is also a response time for fetching a single css. And it's WAY better if you don't include all css.

Comment: Concerning response time : you should probably use client side caching so that browsers only download each variation once

http://www.sitepoint.com/caching-php-performance/

Comment: thanks may be that  few microseconds doesn't slow down the site as  much as than loading time for the extra content

Comment: Exactly what I said, it's the best way in my opinion.